# Vim mappings / plugin for Xcode

Tags: keyboard, emacs, xcode, macvim

I'm a developer who mostly does web stuff in Ruby and C#, and I'd like to start tinkering with iOS and Mac development.

Over the last few month I've been trying to get fluent in one set of key bindings. I chose vi/vim because it just feels right.

I have the awesome ViEmu installed for Visual Studio on Windows which gives me a ton of the vim awesomeness side by side with Visual Studio power toys.

Is there anything like this for Xcode?

I know I could set up MacVim as the default editor but I'm not too interested in this as it means losing all of Xcode's Cocoa awareness.

The other option, of course, would be to go for the lowest common denominator and switch to emacs (as the Cocoa keybindings are based massively on emacs) but let's not think about that for too long.

Answer (score 4):

There are [XVim](https://github.com/JugglerShu/XVim) and [xVim](https://github.com/WarWithinMe/xVim) plugins for Xcode, they are made exactly for this.

You can also use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/) for this (from answer on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085519/as-a-vim-user-how-do-i-get-used-to-xcode) and this [blog](https://zachwill.posterous.com/xcode-and-vi)):

[image]